# search income from a series of option stored in different rows in a table

Tags: mysql

i am trying to make a search system in which i was able to make a filter with such as of age . But there is also a option to filter the users with a specific income they earn to atmost second salary option.

for eg

from income -$25,001 - 40,000

to income - $80,001 - 100,000

so i want to search all users from these income

the table structure is like

[image]

the above table is the income table .

and there is a user table in which there is only one value from the above options

such as $25,001 - 40,000 for user id 1

so how to search all users between 
$25,001-40,000 to $80,001 - 100,000

Comment: Post structure, sample data and desired output in tabular form (not a picture). That might help you to get your answer faster.

Comment: Your table design is not good for what you need to do. You should have the salary information in two separate columns (`SalaryLow` and `SalaryHigh`, for instance), and then you could simply use a `WHERE` clause to find the rows that were between the two ranges. You could also use the proper data type for your salary information.

Comment: yes in case if i dont have a option now to re structure the table . can there be a solution for this?

Comment: @user1001176: If you can't restructure the table, you should create a view that synthesises `SalaryLow` and `SalaryHigh` columns. This isn't a simple problem, however, and I have no idea how to expect different currencies to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like your Income levels have sequential ids, but the best way to do this would be to alter that table so that you have a RangeMinimumIncome and RangeMaximumIncome on this table. Then you could do something like:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
   Income
WHERE
   RangeMinimumIncome >= 25000 AND RangeMinimumIncome <= 100000
   RangeMaximumIncome >= 25000 AND RangeMaximumIncome <= 100000
```

Alternatively you could do something similiar with your Id column but that would require those Ids to always be in the correct order which is an assumption that shouldn't ever be made.

Comment: I said the same thing in a comment to the question, and the poster said that altering the schema was not an option (five minutes before you posted your answer). This doesn't answer the question asked (which is why I posted mine as a comment instead of an answer, BTW).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question asked, either. It doesn't ask for a poor hack to get around the issue, and a query based on ID is exactly that (a poor hack). I have to downvote, because you don't answer the question asked at all. I offered a chance for you to edit or delete your answer first. Sorry. Answers posted should do exactly that - answer the question asked. If you have suggestions, either include them *after answering the question*, or post them as a comment to the question once you have sufficient rep (50) to do so.

Comment: Actually it would answer his question exactly. It's not ideal but he's dealing with a non-ideal situation. The first option I gave is not feasable due to constraints on changing the table, but he could very well use my second suggestion given his circumstances. He could select all ids between x and y with a given currency. If he has control over input of data to this table then he could manage it to make sure that Ids are always in the correct order with respect to salary ranges.

Comment: "What color should I paint my house?" "You should buy a new house instead, or plant a new garden at your neighbor's house." It does **not** answer the question asked with either solution you propose; the first does not work with the poster's requirements, and the second is an unreliable kludge that does not query the salary column as the question asks. This isn't a debate, anyway. IMO, your answer is wrong because it does not answer the question asked, and it's my vote to cast. I was being polite by explaining why I downvoted. StackOverflow does not require me to do so. :-)

Comment: I wasn't debating you in hopes of getting my precious 1 point back. You're free to do whatever you want with your votes. I was simply offering my reasoning as you so graciously offered yours. And your analogy would be better as: What color should I paint my house? A: You should use Home Depot's color selector. B: Sorry I don't have access to Home Depot. A: Then close your eyes and pick a random color at the paint store.

Comment: :-) No problem. (It's 2 points, BTW; my vote cost me one, and you two.)